# DJango - Redirect to another apps / from a button click

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to redirect my user to another apps root on a button click.

So I've two apps, 'portfolio' and 'blogs'.

'blogs' is the main app which loads first.

I've been able to navigate to 'portfolio' app from 'blogs', but how can I do it the other way around?

My Project urls.py

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('portfolio/', include('portfolio.urls')),
    path('', include('blogs.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Anyways, I've figured it out.
Simply added {% url 'myapp:my_url_name' %} to my <a> tags href.

also added app_name = 'blogs' in blogs urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Django URL tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:view-name' %}">My link</a>
```

Example :

```
<a href="{% url 'portfolio:view-name' %}">Portfolio</a>
```